# split timestamp into two seperate columns as date and time in python

Tags: python

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import arrow
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

# import pandas_datareader as datareader

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc

def get_quote_data(symbol='GOOGL', data_range='1d', data_interval='60m'):
    res = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}?range={data_range}&interval={data_interval}'.format(**locals()))
    data = res.json()
    body = data['chart']['result'][0]    
    dt = datetime.datetime
    dt = pd.Series(map(lambda x: arrow.get(x).to('US/Central').datetime.replace(tzinfo=None), body['timestamp']), name='Datetime')
    df = pd.DataFrame(body['indicators']['quote'][0], index=dt)
    dg = pd.DataFrame(body['timestamp'])   
    df = df.loc[:, ('open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume')]
    df.dropna(inplace=True)     #removing NaN rows
    df.columns = ['OPEN', 'HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME']    #Renaming columns in pandas

    return df

data = get_quote_data('BKNG', '30d', '60m')
#data1 = get_quote_data('BKNG', '1d', '60m')
print(data)

#print(data1)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------
                           OPEN         HIGH          LOW        CLOSE  \
Datetime                                                                  
2019-05-31 08:30:00  1653.254517  1658.060059  1640.535156  1656.219971   
2019-05-31 09:30:00  1656.989990  1662.140015  1650.270020  1660.010010   
2019-05-31 10:30:00  1660.000000  1660.790039  1651.060059  1655.670044   
2019-05-31 11:30:00  1654.709961  1658.079956  1650.050049  1657.474976   
2019-05-31 12:30:00  1658.890015  1660.175049  1655.750000  1656.390015   
2019-05-31 13:30:00  1657.060059  1658.599976  1653.589966  1654.650024   
2019-05-31 14:30:00  1654.530029  1658.140015  1653.550049  1655.000000   
2019-06-03 08:30:00  1658.500000  1675.944946  1658.349976  1671.275024   
2019-06-03 09:30:00  1671.355103  1692.209961  1671.119995  1672.280029   
2019-06-03 10:30:00  1672.064941  1672.229980  1652.170044  1653.640015   
2019-06-03 11:30:00  1654.339966  1660.430054  1652.058350  1658.910034   
2019-06-03 12:30:00  1659.510010  1664.099976  1653.974976  1655.989990   
2019-06-03 13:30:00  1655.540039  1657.930054  1649.300049  1650.000000   
2019-06-03 14:30:00  1650.000000  1654.020020  1648.377930  1650.699951   
2019-06-04 08:30:00  1675.989990  1722.469971  1674.390015  1720.469971   
2019-06-04 09:30:00  1720.469971  1729.280029  1715.050049  1727.359985   
2019-06-04 10:30:00  1727.364990  1730.989990  1722.060059  1727.930054
```

I want to split the first column "time stamp" into two separate columns in "Date" and "Time" separately. Please help.

Comment: def get_quote_data(symbol='GOOGL', data_range='1d', data_interval='60m'):
    res = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}?range={data_range}&interval={data_interval}'.format(**locals()))
    data = res.json()
    body = data['chart']['result'][0]    
    dt = datetime.datetime
    dt = pd.Series(map(lambda x: arrow.get(x).to('US/Central').datetime.replace(tzinfo=None), body['timestamp']), name='Datetime')
    df = pd.DataFrame(body['indicators']['quote'][0], index=dt)

Comment: Try to focus your question on your question, avoiding to fill it with lots of unexplained details which don't help to get the context. It makes it difficult to read, therefore harder to help you. Also, try to add what you tried by yourself and where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['date'] = df['timestamp'].date
df['time'] = df['timestamp'].time
```

Hope this helps!

For more info, you can look at [pandas to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime).

Comment: i) I don't see any pd.to_datetime in your code. ii) neither do I see any .date nor .time.  Apart from that, your question is really unreadable, so I really tried to focus on your last sentence, the actual question, and share the solution I usually use when I need to accomplish what you're describing. Improve the question, and answers will surely be better!

Comment: Thanks.. this was my first question posted .. I will redo question .. thanks.